# Connecting toilet vertically to a horizontal T with a 45

Tags: plumbing, toilet, flange, canada

I always see toilets connected to an elbow then drain to Y with a short horizontal pipe. Is there an issue with connecting a toilet flange directly to the 45 deg pipe inserted in a Y directly under the flange? I still have vent pipe close to connection. I'm worried it will not pass inspection in Ontario, Canada.

[image: drawing of what I want to do]

Comment: Why do you need a separate cleanout to service *only* a toilet flange?  You can just remove the toilet once per decade if you need to.   If the drain is close to the flange, use a 90 degree closet elbow and attach the vent just below the bottom of the drawing, and you eliminate the whole upper section.

Comment: thank you for idea but question was about toilet going directly into y with out an elbow.

Answer (score 0):

Toilet flange to 45 to Y is perfectly ok.

Comment: thank you for your time